# get combination from a list of key-values

Tags: c#, combinations

I have a `dict<string, list<string>>,` say 3 keys in dict, the first key has 2 values, the secodn 3 values, the third key has 3 values.  If I get a value from each value set, then I will have a combination of 2*3*3 = 18 sets
How to code in c#?

thanks

Edit 
Sorry did not make it clear

I want something like this 
say I have dict like this

```
 {"1",new List<String>(){"a", "b"}}, 
    {"2",new List<String>(){"c", "d", "e"}}, 
 {"3", new List<string>() {"f", "g"}
```

I want output like this 
acf, acg, adf, adg, aef, aeg
bcf, bcg, bdf, bdg, bef, beg

Comment: +1 for using repeated keys in a dictionary!  You'll have to show me how you did that.

Comment: @Simon  No, the # keys in dict is not fixed.  I just put an example say 3.

Comment: could you give an example of input and expected result?

Comment: @toosensitive I see, have you been thinking about creating a recursive function to do the job?

Comment: In a dictionary every key has exactly one associated value. Explain "the first key has 2 values"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick & dirty but you may polish this method. The result list contains expected result:

Usage:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>() { 
    {"1",new List<String>(){"a", "b"}},
    {"2",new List<String>(){"c", "d", "e"}},
    {"3",new List<String>(){"f", "g"}},
};

var collections = dict.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToArray();            
var result = new List<string>(); 
GetNextProduct(collections, 0, String.Empty, result);
```

Method that produces the result:

```
private static void GetNextProduct(IEnumerable<string>[] collections, int collectionIndex, string currentProduct, IList<string> results)
{
    var currentList = collections[collectionIndex];
    bool isLast = collections.Length == collectionIndex + 1;
    foreach (var s in currentList)
    {
        if (isLast) results.Add(currentProduct + s);
        else GetNextProduct(collections, collectionIndex + 1, currentProduct + s, results);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Linq:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>() { 
    {"1",new List<String>(){"a", "b"}},
    {"2",new List<String>(){"c", "d", "e"}},
    {"3",new List<String>(){"f", "g", "h"}},
};
var combis = from kv in dict
             from val1 in kv.Value
             from val2 in kv.Value
             select string.Format("{0}{1}", val1, val2);
foreach (var combi in combis)
    Console.WriteLine(combi);
```

demo: http://ideone.com/nm7mY

Comment: @Desolator: I'm not 100% sure that this is what OP wants, but it returns all combinations of all values in the dictionary. Have a look at the demo provided.

Comment: +1 this is short an elegant but you would have to modify it if the number of elements in the dictionary changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this?

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    { "Hello World", 1 },
    { "HelloWorld", 1 },
    { "Hello  World", 1 },
};

foreach (var item in dict) // var is of type KeyValuePair<string, int>
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key + ", " + item.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Dictionary<string, List<int>> storage = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
        storage.Add("key1", new List<int>() { 2, 7 });
        storage.Add("key2", new List<int>() { 8, 4, 1});
        storage.Add("key3", new List<int>() { 3, 9, 3 });
        foreach (string key in storage.Keys)
        {
            //access to single storage...
            List<int> subStorage = (List<int>)storage[key];
            foreach (int item in subStorage)
            {
                //access to single value inside storage...
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like the following if I was trying to read or edit the values in the lists:

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
var arrayOfValues = dict.Values.ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfValues.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayOfValues[i].Count; j++)
    {
        //read/edit arrayOfValues[i][j];
    }
}
```

You do not need recursion since you know the dept of the "tree".